# Google maps API use on a device with no google services license

Tags: android

Let's say i have an xaiomi device that doesn't have a license for using google apps(Google App Services) but only have the android system on it(hence the device is suppose to be more cheap). So is an app that uses a google map services can be used in the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When you try using the Play Services SDK, it will look for the Play Services Framework and not find it and give you some sort of unrecoverable error.

Your choices are:

1. Build the app using something other than Play Services (e.g., OpenStreetMap or MapBox for maps instead of Maps V2).
2. Use different product flavors of your app for different distribution channels (e.g., a `google` flavor for distribution through the Play Store and an `other` flavor for distribution outside of the Play Store). You can use Play Services in the Play Store flavor and use some alternative for the non-Play Store flavor. This is more work, but if you feel that the Play Services results will be much better for the user, it may be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question though, if i use google maps V1, will it work?

Comment: @liranahum: No. Partially, that is because you cannot get license keys for Maps V1 anymore. Partially, that is because Maps V1 only worked on devices that license the Google proprietary apps, and so you are back to the same problem. You could use a `WebView` and Google's JavaScript-based maps, presumably.